# What Are the Suggested Resources for Extensive Knowledge About the Fourier Transform (DFT, FFT, etc...)?

Tags: matlab, fft, fourier-transform, dft, self-study

I would like to improve my knowledge about *Fourier Transform* and related subjects.

What are the recommended resources in order to self study about it?

Comment: You should do some reading in the topic. There are many journals, papers and textbooks on the subject. I don't think anyone is going to sit down and write up a massive article on it. BUT, if you look on even this site, there are a number of useful questions

Comment: @Royi Maybe the community should get to mark after [some time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaL1O.png)

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon, I proposed that before. If an answer get enough votes then a moderator can put it to a test for the community if it should be marked or something like that.

Answer (score 6):

Get, Read and Solve the following books:

- [Signals and Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0138147574).
- [Discrete Time Signal Processing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137549202).
- [Digital Signal Processing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132146355).

Take the following courses:

- [Coursera - Digital Signal Processing](https://www.coursera.org/learn/dsp).
- [edX - Discrete Time Signal Processing](https://www.edx.org/course/discrete-time-signal-processing-mitx-6-341x-1).
- edX - Signals and Systems: [Part I](https://www.edx.org/course/signals-and-systems-part-1-1), [Part II](https://www.edx.org/course/signals-systems-part-2-iitbombayx-ee210-2x-3).
- edx - Discrete Time Signals and Systems: [Part 1: Time Domain](https://www.edx.org/course/discrete-time-signals-systems-part-1-ricex-elec301-1x), [Part 2: Frequency Domain](https://www.edx.org/course/discrete-time-signals-systems-part-2-ricex-elec301-2x).
- [edX - Differential Equations: Fourier Series and Partial Differential Equations](https://www.edx.org/course/differential-equations-fourier-series-and-partial-differential-equations-2).

Once you have specific questions, come back here and we'll assist you.